# How to put an image in the middle of text

Tags: html, css, image, text

I'm trying to have an image in the center of a paragraph. Is this possible or will I have to have it to one of the sides?

HTML:

```
<p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</p>

<img id="Riding" src="Images/Jay/Riding.png">
```

CSS:

```
section img {
width: 525px;
display: block;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: you can make text wrap around the image(not fully) but never seen image in middle of text before

Comment: Why not put the image tag in the paragraph? And I'm assuming you want the text to float around the image, so that the image doesn't overlap and hide any text?

Comment: Exactly @MichaelCoker

Comment: I don't think you can do that outside of just putting the image in the paragraph http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpYZjr

Comment: Maybe if you gave us a picture of what you're trying to do or describe the actual project/goal, we might have an approach or alternative.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add `margin:auto` instead of your `margin:auto` and it should put your image in the middle.